# Spherical coordinate question

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

[image: q]

For this question I tried to use spherical coordinates but can't seem to find the interval for $\phi$. Also tried to use change of coordinates but no luck, any help is appreciated

Comment: did u notice that $\frac{z}{|\overrightarrow{\rm x}|} = cosφ$ ?

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first inequality defines a spherical shell.

The second really seems a typo, maybe it should be:

$$\gamma \leq \cos \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} =\cos \frac{z}{\rho}=\cos \phi \leq \delta$$

[image]